# Efficient way to initialize a nested object in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I have a User class with a nested Address class. In the component I would like to initialize an object of type User with something like `let user = new User()` or `let user:User`.

But errors are thrown, because Angular/Typescript wants me to assign values. Is there an efficient way to do this, without assigning all the empty `""` values to the object.

Below the classes:

```
class Address {
    constructor(
        public street: string,
        public number: number,
        public suffix: string,
        public houseLetter: string,
        public city: string,
        public zipcode: string,
    ) { }
}

export class User {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public email: string,
        public address: Address,
    ) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark these parameters as `optional` like this:

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public firstName?: string,
        public lastName?: string,
        public email?: string,
        public address?: Address,
    ) { }
}
```

now you can easily instantiate user object with 
`let user = new User()`

[Working demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcrplg)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

**Model**

```
export class AddressModel {
    constructor(data?: any) {
    if (data != null) {
        this.street = data.street;
        this.number = data.number;
        this.suffix = data.suffix;
        this.houseLetter = data.houseLetter;
        this.city = data.city;
        this.zipcode = data.zipcode;
    }
 }
        public street: string = null;
        public number: number = null;
        public suffix: string = null;
        public houseLetter: string = null;
        public city: string = null;
        public zipcode: string = null;
}
```

**TS**

```
someFunction() {
let data = new AddressModel({data to pass}); // here we are passing the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern:

```
export class Address {
    street: string;
    number: number;
    suffix: string;
    houseLetter: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;

    constructor(values? : Partial<Address>)
    { 
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}

export class User {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    address: Address;
    constructor(values? : Partial<User>)
    { 
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const p1 = new User();

const p2 = new User({
  firstName: 'paul',
  address: new Address({
    street: '1 st james street'
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine:

```
export class User {
  public id: number = 0;
  public firstName: string = "";
  public lastName: string = "";
  public email: string = "";
}
```

In TS:

```
user = new User();
 constructor() {
  console.log(this.user); // {"id":0,"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":""}
}
```

[`Online_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtpnan)